# Can't extend Macintosh HD partition after removing Linux

Tags: partition

I toyed around with Linux, and after discovering that the offical Linux NVidia drivers doesn't have EFI support which makes it impossible to make it work optimally on my system (bummer), I wanted to remove it.

I deleted the partitions with Disk Utility, except the swap partition which I deleted with GParted.
My disk looks like this now in Disk Utility:
[image]

Now when I try to extend the Macintosh HD partition to fill the entire disk and click Apply, it gets stuck at checking the catalog file and gives me an error.
[image]

*Translation (I don't know what it's exactly like in the English version of OSX): Partitioning failed - The partitioning failed with the error: The partition-layout cannot be changed, because the file system could not be checked.*

When I try it with GParted, I can't move the handles for some reason.

How can I make Macintosh HD fill the entire disk again, other than formatting the disk and restoring a Time Machine backup?

EDIT: When I click the button to check the disk for errors it says there's nothing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try run Disk Utility from Recovery Mode as described in http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4718

Comment: Recovery will work for checking & repairing the main partition, but will not allow repartitioning. This is because recovery mode runs from a small, invisible partition right after (/below) the regular system partition, and in order to expand/shrink the regular system partition, it needs to move the recovery partition, and it can't do that while you're booted from it.

Comment: When I try that it asks me for my Wi-Fi password and it keeps saying my password is incorrect while it I'm sure I entered it right.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was just to insert the original linux installation disc, go to the partition page again. Hover around and finally successfully get rid of the ext3 (mine one that cannot be removed by the mac disk utility program) partition. Then I went back to Mac again, this time the resizing/repartitioning worked, yeah!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I already did it by formatting my hard drive and then restoring files from Time Machine. Thanks for bothering to answer, however.